# Using Mysql Trigger BEFORE INSERT for Default Value

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created a BEFORE INSERT trigger on a Mysql table. I want to create a default value behavior for a date field in mySQL 5.4. This means I want to use the value from the trigger if no value is provided for this field at the insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `be_table1` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.`date_joined` = NOW();
```

This works so far. But if I now insert data into my table like this ...

```
INSERT INTO table1 (date_joined, productname) VALUES ('2001-02-10', 'hello world');
```

... **not '2001-02-10' is inserted, but the current date**.

As far as I understood the BEFORE INSERT trigger, it pre-populates the field and should be overwritten by the insert statement. Am I wrong?

Comment: MySQL 5.4 is downright ancient at this point. If you can upgrade to 5.7 or 8.0 you'll see *considerable* performance benefits.

Comment: Can you add a `WHERE NEW.date_joined IS NULL` clause?

Comment: Thanks. Where can I add this clause? I get a syntax error if I put it right behind Now()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **modify** the values to be inserted in the `before insert` trigger, not pre-populate it!

You can use `coalesce()` function to override the `NEW` value only if it is `null`:

```
...
SET NEW.`date_joined` = COALESCE(NEW.`date_joined`, NOW());
```

Comment: In MySQL this is also known as `IFNULL()`, though `COALESCE()` is more in line with the SQL standard.